# ¿Cómo crear enlace simbólico mediante comandos?

Tags: android

He formulado esta pregunta con el fin de que me pudiesen corregir, orientar y enseñar, sobre el tema de los enlaces en `android`, porque normalmente los creo en Java en mediante la clase Files, pero en `android` no se encuentra esta clase.

Así que quiero lograr crear un enlace en `android` de un archivo que se encuentra en la `sdcard` he encontrado un método de `android` que es `Os.symlink` este no me funciona porque es para `android 21` y lo necesito mínimo para la 14. Pero creo que encontré la manera y es mediante comandos, pero el problema es que cuando los ejecuto no crea nada.

Mis códigos manejados:

a)Primer código:

```
                try { 
               // Preform su to get root privledges
               p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ln [-fhinsv] /sdcard/Enlace.txt /sdcard/Mob/Enlace.txt"); 
               Toast.makeText(this, "creado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) { 
               // TODO Code to run in input/output exception
                //toastMessage("not root"); 
            }
```

b)Segundo intento:

```
                try { 
               // Preform su to get root privledges
               p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ln -s /sdcard/Enlace.txt /sdcard/Mob/Enlace.txt"); 
               Toast.makeText(this, "creado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




            } catch (IOException e) { 
               // TODO Code to run in input/output exception
                //toastMessage("not root"); 
            }
```

c)Tercer intento:

```
                try { 
               // Preform su to get root privledges
               p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ln -sv /sdcard/Enlace.txt /sdcard/Mob/Enlace.txt"); 
               Toast.makeText(this, "creado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




            } catch (IOException e) { 
               // TODO Code to run in input/output exception
                //toastMessage("not root"); 
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta

> ln -f -r -s /sdcard/Enlace.txt /usr/bin/Enlace.txt

Comment: Amigo continua sin crear nada utilice y pero modifique una parte de su código: **ln -f -r -s /sdcard/Enlace.txt /usr/bin/Enlace.txt**.Gracias